# problema al imprimir registros con foreach

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, php7, foreach

Cuando realizo el `foreach` en 2 registros, al hacer `JOIN` por alguna razón se me va a 4, si hago de 3 registros se me va a 11 resultados, de 4 registros se me va a 50 resultados y así sucesivamente...

Lo que busco es que al hacer `foreach` en `x` registros, me imprima `x` como se debe.

**ej: busco 77 registros y me imprima los 77 registros**

*error: busco 77 registros y me imprime 8000 registros*

```
$conexion = new mysqli("blabla","blabla","blabla","blabla");
$query   = "SELECT * FROM post p JOIN  enlaces e ON p.id_enlace";
$post_bd = $conexion->query($query);
$conexion->close();
foreach ($post_bd as $row){
    $cargando[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($cargando);
```

**acá quiero imprimir 2 registros, pero me está imprimiendo 4**

```
0: {id_enlace: "70", imagen: "img/imagenes_preguntas/UuomezaNxVGdOKyHLJECRiTgsFrQjtpISfcWZYXPBkhvqlwDMbAv.jpeg", titulo: "afasfasf", contenido: "asdasd", id: "70", …}
1: {id_enlace: "71", imagen: "img/imagenes_preguntas/JbZIGojLYEXTDhmrOpzPUBcqKgtliAQwkxvMVsHyuNdeSFRfWaCd.jpeg", titulo: "asdasd", contenido: "sdfsdf", id: "70", …}
2: {id_enlace: "70", imagen: "img/imagenes_preguntas/UuomezaNxVGdOKyHLJECRiTgsFrQjtpISfcWZYXPBkhvqlwDMbAv.jpeg", titulo: "afasfasf", contenido: "asdasd", id: "71", …}
3: {id_enlace: "71", imagen: "img/imagenes_preguntas/JbZIGojLYEXTDhmrOpzPUBcqKgtliAQwkxvMVsHyuNdeSFRfWaCd.jpeg", titulo: "asdasd", contenido: "sdfsdf", id: "71", …}
```

---

[image: acá la imagen de phpMyAdmin, imprime lo mismo]

acá la imagen de phpMyAdmin, imprime lo mismo que les comenté

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que _mySQL_ no devuelve un error con la sentencia `SELECT * FROM post p JOIN  enlaces e ON p.id_enlace`? Pregunto, porque la sentencia está mal formada. Si el motor la acepta y la ejecuta, probablemente está devolviendo la cantidad de registros que ves. ¿La has ejecutado directamente sobre el motor, digamos con phpMyAdmin o algo similar?

Comment: sí deecho saque una screendshot, no me deja adjuntarla acá, míra la respuesta general ahí dejaré la imagen

Comment: Generalmente no hace falta screenshots. Solo confirma cuantos registros está devolviendo el motor. Si devuelve 2, el problema está en el `foreach`, si devuelve 4, el problema está en la consulta SQL, al que le falta la mitad de la condición del `join` que, según veo, debiera tener la forma `on p.id_enlace = e.id` o como se llame el campo de llave primaria de la tabla `enlaces`.

Comment: señor, le agradezco rotundamente por brindarme su conocimiento, estuve todo el día con este error.. muchísimas gracias!!!!

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, no esperaría que mySQL aceptara algo así, pero ya que lo hace, si replanteas la pregunta para enfocarla en por qué MySQL te devuelve 4 registros cuando esperas 2, podría responderla y así esto queda por si en el futuro es de ayuda para alguien más.

Comment: Tu código de lectura es muy extraño. Generalmente se usa algún método `fetch` para leer los datos, pero no veo que uses ninguno. En lugar del `foreach` prueba esto y verifica si ahora te devuelve los datos correctamente: `while ($row = $post_bd->fetch_assoc()) { $cargando[] = $row; }` Y luego: `$conexion->close();`   OJO: cierra la conexión después del `while` no antes, como haces en tu código actual. Son realmente extrañas las prácticas que veo en tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano debo cambiar el método que utilizo para recorrer los datos? estoy realizando una mala práctica? si es así porfavor dímelo que cambiaré la forma de hacerlo, de lo contrario si no es una mala práctica, no veo la necesidad de hacerlo

Comment: Es una práctica no convencional... de hecho, me extraña que tu código funcione de este modo. Según la documentación `mysqli` tiene los métodos `fetch_` para leer los  datos obtenidos en una consulta. Si observas los ejemplos de código [en el Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), se abre un bucle invocando alguno de los métodos `fetch_`. En cuanto a la conexión, por lo general ésta se cierra una vez hayas terminado de leer los datos, no antes, como podrás ver en los ejemplos del mismo enlace.

Comment: @A.Cedano buenísimo, de echo esta solución para recorrer datos y pasarlo a objetos lo vi en una respuesta de stackoverflow, de igual manera voy a leerme el manual para no ensuciar mi código, gracias por corregirme otro error que probablemente me ensucie a futuro en ámbito laboral